# sqlalchemy single parent overly restrictive

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 models,

```
class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TableA'

    table_b_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('TableB.id'), primary_key=True)

    table_b = relationship('TableB', back_populates='table_a', single_parent=True)
```

and

```
class TableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TableB'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = Column(String, nullable=True)

    table_a = relationship('TableA', back_populates='table_b', cascade='all,delete')
```

so if I create a `table_b = TableB(date='20210714')` and then create two instances of table A like `table_a = TableA(table_b=table_b)` and `table_aa = TableA(table_b=table_b)`, it will fail on the second `table_aa` creation

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance <TableB at 0x7f4edec715b0> is already associated with an instance of <class 'something'> via its TableA.table_b attribute, and is only allowed a single parent. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/bbf1)
```

I thought single parent just meant that every TableA instance can only be associate with 1 TableB? This seems like there can only be 1 TableB instance related to a TableA in the database, kind of like a `single_child` ish restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key values must be unique. You're attempting to create two instances of TableA both using the same TableB.id value. I'm not sure what specific problem you're trying to solve here but I think you want to drop the primary_key attribute from table_b_id and add a separate primary_key for TableA.